# Save the user input parameters in perl config file from xaml file

Tags: c#, xaml, app-config

I have a application which was developed using perl and its UI is designed by xaml and c# files in visual studio. So now I had created a confilg file in perl where the source code files uses this config file to read inputs from. For that I want to save the parameters into the perl config file that I had created already from user input xaml file and c# as binding for GUI. I want to know if there is a way to save the paramerts to perl file using xaml and c# file in visual studio.

Here is an example for xaml file and c# binding file from GUI of the tool.

**xaml file:**

```
<TabItem Header="Properties" x:Name="tabItem1_Copy" Margin="-2,-2,-2,0">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,4.2,2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Height="20" Margin="295,58,0,0" x:Name="tbShiftColumns" Width="40" />
        <TextBlock Height="20" x:Name="textBlock7" Text="Shift Columns" Width="75" />
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

**xaml.cs file:**

```
 private void bxxxxxx_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tFLog.Clear();

        Process prc = new Process();
        prc.StartInfo.FileName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.bat";
        prc.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + tbCustPar.Text + "\" \"" + tbShiftColumns.Text + "\"";
        prc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;//.Hidden;
        prc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        prc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection);
        prc.Start();
        prc.WaitForExit();
        prc.Close();

        string logFileName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection) + "\\xxxx.log";
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(logFileName, System.Text.Encoding.Default, true);
        tFLog.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

and in the above 2 example codes once can observe tbshift columns is one of the input parameters in .xaml file and it is binded using c# .xaml.cs file. that is what i mean. Now I want to find a way to save the user input parameters directly into a perl config file. I already created one and will be displayed below for reference.

**perl config file:**

```
#variables to be parsed to xyz.pl file

maxDepth = tbNoLevels
shiftt = tbshiftColumns
```

I hope I had explained my problem as clear as possible. Any suggestion or answers are highly appriciated.

Thank you

I tried to create a **app.config** file in visual studio and it looked like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

I think here we can add dictionaries like key and value pairs : `<add key="Key0" value="0" />`

but I want to save the input parameters directly into a perl config file.

And I also tried to create a **App.xaml** file this has:

```
<Application x:Class="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="xxxxxxxx.xaml"\>
    <Application.Resources\>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I have no idea what can be done. Any proper direction of action to solve is issue is highly expected. Or suggest any other alternatives to achieve this. I am beginner I would expect a detailed answer please.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for. The snippet under _perl config file_ has nothing to do with perl.

Comment: Hello @clamp, I am trying to save the input parameter values that are given by user in xaml file(visual studio) to perl config file. simply want to parse user input paramerts to perl file and save them in it. Need help with this.